# Cannot Resolve Action, even though my action exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hopefully a really simple MVC problem (), I have a controller in my **Controllers** folder called **HomeController** which contains a method called **Index** which looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

My Index view does indeed exist, and on my shared Layout view I have the following link (to my index page)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")
```

Am I doing this right? I have a method called **Index** in my controller which returns my **Index** view, so shouldn't this ActionLink work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionLink takes the action name and then the controller name.

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link", "Index", "Home");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @JMK `@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home")`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not just me who got confused by this then, good to know!